# How to iterate Chef roles attribute using the chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, newrelic

I am trying to create a newrelic chef recipe to configure multiple applications one server(multiple xml file creation) and also we need to pass the environment, it would be great if someone please advise. Thank you.

trying the below syntax:

Role File:

```
override_attributes({
   'applications' => [
    ["app1Name", “app1Server”, 755, “admin”, “admin”],
    ["app2Name", “app2Server”, 755, “admin”, “admin”],
    ["app3Name", “app3Server”, 755, “admin”, “admin”]
    ]
    })
```

Receipe File:

```
node['applications'].each do |appdetails|
    template"#{path_loc}/newrelic_#{appdetails[0]}.yml do
       cookbook 'cookbook_name'
       source 'new relic.yml' 
       action :create
       ignore_failure true
      end
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how you do it, though usually with a bit more readability.

Comment: But when Iam running through kitchen converge it throws me an error says role is defined at top level but does not exists, I am trying to execute the role with the recipe attached to role and updated the .kitchen.yml file with runlist as role, please advise the way Iam doing is correct? Thank you

Comment: Most likely you aren't setting things up to run the role inside Test Kitchen correctly. This is a somewhat rare thing to do since Test Kitchen is mostly for testing cookbooks, not roles.